# Data table fread error reading Latin-1 file containing NUL byte <0x00>

Tags: r, character-encoding, data.table

Having trouble creating a reproducible example and can't share the data, but I think I stumbled upon a bug in fread(). Trying to read my 1.658GB tsv file encoded in Latin-1 produces the following error:

```
Error in fread("POANG.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", sep2 = NULL, encoding = "Latin-1",  :
  Jump 949 did not finish counting rows exactly where jump 950 found its first good line start: prevEnd(0x14e51d6dc)<<>> != thisStart(prevEnd+180966)<<4908565  01  0   1   0   1999    1   TNMAT       NMAC09  015 015 15.>>
```

The problematic line is line no 11129896 where there is a NUL mark written out as `<0x00>` in Sublime Text and `^@` in Vi (can't copy it). If i set `skip = 11129895`, fread throws the same error but now on "jump 0", if I set `skip = 11129896` it works, but `nrows=11129895` still throws the same error.

Comment: I'd suggest posting it to their github rather than stackoverflow if you really think you found a bug.

Comment: Was going to do that but then they have the following in the instructions for posting issues: "3. searched and asked on [Stack Overflow's data.table tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table) and will provide a link to the question(s)"

Comment: Can you please copy here the line containing the bad character (and perhaps a previous/next line)? If there's sensitive information there, then you can replace all letters with `A`s and all digits with 1s.

Comment: The problem is that when i try to copy it the character disappears. Now tried to edit the file using Sublime to remove all other rows and then save it, and while the NULL character is still there, fread does not throw an error anymore. Really strange, but I guess it must be some kind of encoding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fixed as of now in v1.12.3 on GitHub. If you still have the file, please try again.